# failed to download openapi: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials, turn validation off with --validate=false

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-eks

I'm encountering an issue while trying to deploy a Laravel application to an AWS EKS cluster using Jenkins. I've set up a Jenkins pipeline with several stages including checking out the latest source code, logging into AWS ECR, building and pushing Docker images to ECR, and finally deploying to the Kubernetes cluster.

Here's my Jenkins pipeline configuration:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        AWS_ACCOUNT_ID="###########"
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1"
        IMAGE_REPO_NAME="ecom-product"
        IMAGE_TAG="${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        REPOSITORY_URI = "###########.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ecom-product"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout Latest Source') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'master',
                url: 'https://github.com/firal345/ecom-product',
                credentialsId: 'jenkins_credential'
            }
        }
        stage('Logging into AWS ECR') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh """aws ecr get-login-password --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com"""
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Building image') {
            steps{
                script {
                    dockerImage = docker.build "${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Pushing to ECR') {
            steps{  
                script {
                    sh """docker tag ${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG} ${REPOSITORY_URI}:$IMAGE_TAG"""
                    sh """docker push ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}"""
                }
            }
        }
        stage('K8S Deploy') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'pwd'
                    sh 'ls'
                    sh 'kubectl version'
                    withKubeConfig([credentialsId: 'K8S']) {
                        sh '''
                            cd deployment
                            cat namespace.yml
                            kubectl apply -f namespace.yml
                        '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an overview of my setup:
**Kubectl Version:**

```
kubectl version
Client Version: v1.29.2
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.29.1-eks-508b6b3
```

**AWS CLI Version:**

```
aws --version
aws-cli/2.15.27 Python/3.11.8 Linux/6.2.0-1018-aws exe/x86_64.ubuntu.22 prompt/off
```

All stages in the pipeline execute successfully until the "K8S Deploy" stage where I attempt to apply the Kubernetes configuration (namespace.yml). However, I encounter the following error in the console:

```
[Pipeline] // withKubeConfig
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Additionally, I see the following error message:

```
error: error validating "deployment/namespace.yml": error validating data: failed to download openapi: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Could someone please assist me in resolving this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!